# Android - When to pass the parent ViewGroup to LayoutInflater.inflate?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-arrayadapter, layout-inflater

I have a simple ListView in my app.  The ListView is binded to my ArrayAdapter class with a `getView` method implemented as follows.

```
class ScheduleListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ScheduleItem> 
{
    @Override public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View view = convertView;

        if (view == null) {
            view = _activity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.schedule_item2, null);
        } 

        // not shown - code initialize elements of view

        return view;
    }
```

In the above code, notice that the `parent` ViewGroup parameter is ignored and not passed to the `inflate` call.  I modeled this code after several books and online examples.

But now I've seen other examples on the web suggest that `parent` needs to be passed to `inflate` as follows:

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.schedule_item2, parent, false);
```

I've tried it both ways and it seems to work fine either way.  But looking at the [source for inflate](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/view/LayoutInflater.java#LayoutInflater.inflate%28org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser%2Candroid.view.ViewGroup%2Cboolean%29), it seems that when the `parent` is passed, it can influence the [LayoutParams](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html) that are used initialize to the view.  But I'm uncertain how to interpret the code beyond this.

It gets confusing when you compare the above to other online examples of using LayoutInflater with Fragments and RecyclerView. Those examples always seem to explicitly pass the `parent` parameter to `inflate`.  I'm assuming there are situations where it makes sense to do this.

Can someone explain when to pass `ViewGroup parent` to `inflate` and when not to?

Comment: Hope this will be helpful: https://possiblemobile.com/2013/05/layout-inflation-as-intended/

Comment: @RohitArya - Thanks!  That blog page is exactly the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a result, **without any known parent**, all LayoutParams you declared on the root element of your XML tree will just get thrown away.
Without LayoutParams, the ViewGroup that eventually hosts the inflated layout is left to generate a default set for you. If you are lucky (and in many cases you are) these default parameters are the same as what you had in XML

Answer (score 1):

Base on this [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html#inflate(int,%20android.view.ViewGroup,%20boolean))

> ViewGroup: **Optional** view to be the parent of the generated hierarchy
> **(if attachToRoot is true)**, or else simply an object that provides a
> set of LayoutParams values for root of the returned hierarchy (if
> attachToRoot is false.)

It means what you experienced.

When to pass: to specify which one is the parent and this `view` must attach to the parent.  If not attached, the only LayoutParamss from `parent` will be used.